# how to access the online archive of an on-premise primary mailbox using EWS in a hybrid environment

Tags: office365, archive, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

the environment here is as followed:

1. I got a hybrid environment of Exchange 2010 SP3 and Office365.

   - *I think the configuration is well working since I can see the user of on-premise Exchange showing up in office365.*
   - *In the OWA, I can only see the archived emails in OWA, but can't archive emails from the primary mailbox, which I don't consider as a pressing issue, but I will feel very happy if anyone tells me why it's not working and make it work.*
   - *In the Outlook, I can do both.*
2. I set up my DNS management to Office365.

   - *I did so by adding a MX record in sth that host my domain, because Office 365 recommend it.*
3. I have a mailbox on the on-premise Exchange 2010 SP3 as the primary mailbox, and enabled the archive located in office 365.

   - *I have online archiving license assigned, so this will probably eliminate the license issues.*
   - *I also have proper 3rd party certificate.*

---

problems:

> 1. (IMPORTANT)I want to access the online archive using EWS, viewing the folders/emails and importing some emails in to it.

- I tried using the EWS Managed API, both Powershell and C# code, but it would broke when binding any folder.

> 2. (NOT IMPORTANT)I want to make the hybrid environment accessible through internet using OUTLOOK.

- I assigned an internet IP to "exchange webservices external url" and opened the 443 port, so I can use the OWA from the internet.
- But I can't use the Outlook to connect it, because it will fail, the test tool of Outlook shows that failure happened when testing auto-discover.

> 3. (NOT IMPORTANT)I want to be able to archive Emails manually through OWA.

- I really don't know y but OWA simply shows me there's a error.

Is there anyone can help me on these, please?

Any suggestions are welcome.

I have been searching the documentations and forums for nearly a month.

Comment: Common, still no one?

Answer (score 0):

problem 1: use autodiscover to get the alternative smtp address, then use this smtp address to bind folders, then it will succeed.

problem 2: put outlook inside the domain.

problem 3: this is a bug of OWA. you can see it but you can't move it.

NOTE: configure SSO if necessary.